# Simplifying the union of two intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to simplify $(E \cup F)\cap(F \cup G)$

My process:

$(E \cup F)\cap (F \cup G)$

$((E \cup F)\cap F) \cup ((E \cup F)\cap G)$

$F \cup (E\cap G) \cup (F\cap G)$

And this is where I get stuck. It should simplify to F ∪ EG, but I'm not sure how to turn $E\cap G ∪ F\cap G$ into $E\cap G$.

Comment: What work have you done on this problem?

Comment: Where, specifically, do you get stuck? Please post your work so far along with the question.

Comment: Well the original problem is to simplify (E ∪ F)(F ∪ G) so this has been my process:

Distribute to get: ((E ∪ F)F) ∪ ((E ∪ F)G)

And this is where the problem I posted begins: F ∪ (EG ∪ FG)

Comment: Please put the process *in the question* using edits.

Comment: Sorry, just edited it.

Comment: Lookup the [absorption laws](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absorption_Laws_(Set_Theory)/Union_with_Intersection).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Commutation. Then what is $F\cup (F\cap G)~\cup (E\cap G)$?

In fact, do so right from the start.

$$\begin{align}&~(E\cup F)\cap (F\cup G)\\ =&~ && \text{Commutation}\\=&~F\cup (E\cap G) && \text{Distribution}\end{align}$$

Two east steps; just fill in the middle one and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you see how to simplify $F\cup FG$? Forget about $E$ for a moment and just draw a Venn diagram for $F$, $G$ and $F\cup FG$.